# Weird behavior of two mouse events being triggered infinitely in tooltip code

Tags: java, popup, mouseevent, javafx-2

I am trying to implement a custom tooltip using the `javafx.stage.Popup`. The sample demo code is:

```
public class PopupDemo extends Application {

    private Popup tooltip;
    private final SepiaTone sepiaTone = new SepiaTone();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("PopupDemo");

        Label content = new Label();
        content.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#FCFBBD; -fx-padding: 5; -fx-border-color: #BFBD3B");

        tooltip = new Popup();
        tooltip.getContent().add(content);

        VBox vbox = new VBox(10);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            final Label lbl = new Label("item " + i);
            lbl.setStyle("-fx-border-color:darkgray; -fx-background-color:lightgray");
            lbl.setMaxSize(80, 60);
            lbl.setMinSize(80, 60);
            lbl.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

            lbl.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(final MouseEvent e) {
                    lbl.setEffect(sepiaTone);
                    lbl.setStyle("-fx-cursor: hand");
                    Label content = (Label) tooltip.getContent().get(0);
                    content.setText(lbl.getText());
                    tooltip.show(lbl, e.getScreenX(), e.getScreenY());
                }
            });
            lbl.setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                    lbl.setEffect(null);
                    lbl.setStyle("-fx-cursor: default");
                    tooltip.hide();
                }
            });

            vbox.getChildren().add(lbl);
        }

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.setPadding(new Insets(20));
        root.getChildren().add(vbox);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

When I move the mouse over the labels the popup shows up and it is working great. But in some cases the two mouse event handlers `OnMouseEntered` and `OnMouseExited` are being called continuously one after another. One can reproduce this by running provided example, maximising a window and hovering labels continuously.

Is there a way to avoid this? I'm using JavaFX 2.0.1. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a classic problem: you put mouse at a point, node receives `MouseEntered` — tooltip appears under the mouse and covers the node triggering `MouseExited`.

To avoid that you can change `tooltip.show(lbl, e.getScreenX(), e.getScreenY())` call to

```
tooltip.show(lbl, e.getScreenX() + 1, e.getScreenY() + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer, so much as pointers to things you might try or investigate further.

You could look at the implementation of `Tooltip` [Skin](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/2.1/master/rt/file/f71b3db3cab9/javafx-ui-controls/src/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/TooltipSkin.java) and [Behavior](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/2.1/master/rt/file/829b27e97eb1/javafx-ui-controls/src/javafx/scene/control/Tooltip.java) to see how it handles some of these cases.

The easiest way to implement a custom popup is just to use a Tooltip, style it the way you need [using css](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#tooltip) and use the Tooltip's [setGraphic method](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/scene/control/Tooltip.html#setGraphic%28javafx.scene.Node%29) to add any custom Node content you want.

If you prefer to use your own implementation, I think you need to keep track of whether the popup has been displayed or not, so you don't try to show it if it is already showing, etc.  You may also need invoke the hiding of the popup by having a mouse exit handler installed on the popup itself.  You also might want a click to dismiss function for the popup by implementing a mouse click handler on the popup.  You should also consider whether you should do a straight subclass of [Popup](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/stage/Popup.html) or [PopupControl](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/scene/control/PopupControl.html), though using Popup as you have is likely more straightforward.

Comment: I am not using `Tooltip` due to 2 reasons,
the `Node`, tooltip applied on, is actually a `Pane` which has not `setTooltip()` method, and i don't want the tooltip disappeared after the tooltip's time is out, thanks for input though.

Comment: You can install a `Tooltip` on any `Node` using the Tooltip's static install method http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/scene/control/Tooltip.html#install%28javafx.scene.Node,%20javafx.scene.control.Tooltip%2  I don't think there is currently (as of JavaFX 2.0) a public API to ignore the Tooltip's time out settings so that the tooltip remains visible.  To achieve that using a Tooltip, you would have to create a custom Tooltip subclass which modifies the `TooltipBehavior` from the open source implementation, which is non-trivial - the custom Popup approach you have is far simpler.

Comment: I created a feature request for more control over Tooltip visibility settings via the public API: http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-19538 (signup required to access link, but anybody can signup).